# Multithreading in java thread declaration

Tags: java, multithreading

These are few lines from my code:

```
class abc {
    public static void main(String br[]){
        Age age=new Age(21);
        Thread th1=new Man("Thread1",age);
        Thread th2=new Woman("Thread2",age);
        th1.start();
        th2.start();
    }
}

class Age
{ 
    int age;
    Age(int a) {
        this.age=a;
    }
}

class Man extends Thread()
{
    Age age;
    Man(String name,Age age)
    {
        super(name);
        this.age=age;
    }
}
```

Woman class is exactly the same.

I have three classes Age,Man,Woman. Can anyone explain what is happening in 2nd and 3rd line? I mean, what is the calling object of the class? What is the calling object of each thread? Also, if I use `this` in my `Man` class, what object will it refer to-the calling object or the `age` 21?

Comment: What is Age? Sub-class of what class? Which interfaces does it implement?

Comment: Also, please show the code of Man and Woman, since we have no way of knowing what parameters their constructors expect.

Comment: I have edited my question,please check

Comment: The code you pasted doesn't even compile. Why would we explain what uncompilable code does? It doesn't do anything, since it doesn't compile. Also, threading is one of the most complex things to use correctly, and you don't seem to understand classes and objects yet, so don't try using threads yet. Learn the basics first.

Comment: Yes,I am really sorry  I know  that but I just want to know how does 2nd and 3rd line works.The entire code is too big and irrelevant to my question,so I made a pseudo code

Answer (score 2):

Your code is meaningless. You are construcing an instance of class Man, which is a sub-class of Thread, but you don't pass any Runnable instance to the constructor of Thread, and you don't override the `run()` method of `Thread` in your `Man` class. This means that when you start the thread, it will execute the default empty `run()` method of `Thread` class, which does nothing and returns immediatelly.

Comment: I have a run () method in Man and Woman classes.As I said this was the part of my code,I have not shown them here.I know this code is meaningless but I have still written this because in the actual code i was not able to understand the 2nd and 3rd line(`Thread th1=new Man("Thread1",age);
    Thread th2=new Woman("Thread2",age);`
The rest of the code I understood and there was no point pasting a 200 line code

Comment: @peter What don't you understand? you are creating an instance of Man which is a sub-class of Thread. You pass to it a String, which is passed to the Thread constructor to serve as the thread name, and an instance of Age which you store as a member of the Man instance. I'm assuming you are doing the same with the Woman instance.

Comment: Yes I have done the same with Woman. As far as I know, I am declaring the thread correctly-here is correct method which I had read and implemented in my code-




`public class ThreadB extends Thread {
    public ThreadB() {
     super("ThreadB");
    }
    public void run() {
     //Code
    }
}`




This is the way to use threads.I think I have done the same.In my case by calling `super(name)` I am giving the thread name-`Thread1` . I am really sorry but I am not able to get what you are trying to say

Comment: @Peter I guess I'm not getting what you are asking. The way you are using Threads in one way to use Threads. Not the recommended way. You should read about [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) and [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for an alternative to the explicit Thread creation you are using.

Comment: @Eran I also have similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949323/how-to-use-tcp-socket-efficiently-in-multiple-threads) on multithreading. See if you can help me out. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

th1.start() and th2.start() calls puts the thread into the 'READY TO RUN' queue, when the thread gets its chance it is moved from 'READY TO RUN' to 'RUNNABLE' (i.e. running in memory) and this is when the run() method of the class gets called.

Different JVMs have different strategy to put threads into RUNNABLE state .
Also based on the implementation of the run() method, the thread reamins in memory or is moved out or is terminated.

calling object of the start() methods are the instance of Thread, in your case it si th1 and th2.